# Oozie - Google cloud storage - Delete a file

Tags: google-cloud-storage, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to delete a file in google cloud from oozie. I am creating a dummy script and executing it through oozie. I have a prepare statement where I say "delete gs://....."

It is not working and the error is "schema gs not supported". How could I delete Google cloud storage files in oozie workflow otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.

I have created a shell script with `hadoop fs -rm` command to delete the files from Google Cloud Storage. The shell script was scheduled from Oozie as well. It solves my issue.